# jquery - How to get the value from a textbox?

Tags: jquery, textbox

Hi everyone Im trying to get the value of textbox whenever the user clicks on the textbox using jquery but when I used alert() to see the values here's what I got:

```
function (value) {
var hooks, ret, elem = this[0];
if (!arguments.length) {
    if (elem) {
        hooks = jQuery.valHooks[elem.nodeName.toLowerCase()] ||
            jQuery.valHooks[elem.type];
        if (hooks &&
            "get" in hooks &&
            (ret = hooks.get(elem, "value")) !== undefined) {
            return ret;
        }
        ret = elem.value;
        return typeof ret === "string" ? ret.replace(rreturn, "") : ret == null ? "" : ret;
    }
    return undefined;
}
var isFunction = jQuery.isFunction(value);
return this.each(function (i) {var self = jQuery(this), val;if (this.nodeType !== 1) {return;}if (isFunction) {val = value.call(this, i, self.val());} else {val = value;}if (val == null) {val = "";} else if (typeof val === "number") {val += "";} else if (jQuery.isArray(val)) {val = jQuery.map(val, function (value) {return value == null ? "" : value + "";});}hooks = jQuery.valHooks[this.nodeName.toLowerCase()] || jQuery.valHooks[this.type];if (!hooks || !("set" in hooks) || hooks.set(this, val, "value") === undefined) {this.value = val;}});}
```

Here is my code: http://jsfiddle.net/QYHXu/1/

Please help. Thanks a lot in advance.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
$(this).val
```

...is a function.

```
$(this).val()
```

...is the return value from that function. Use `$(this).val()`.

Answer (score 3):

Change your `val` function

From

```
$(this).val);
```

To

```
$(this).val());
```

Comment: His jsFiddle was more to show what his problem was than to show an example of a use case.

Answer (score 3):

you have forgotten the parenthesis dude for val function :)

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
$(function(){
    $('input#txtName').click(function () {
        alert(document.getElementById('txtName').value);
    });
});
```